# Java and database

Tags: java, database, jtable

English is not my first language, so sorry if there is a mistake in the grammar.

My question is, I have a database where I have bills, so when the bills are paid, I put a `C` of cancel in the table. Now, I am trying to do something in java, I want my jtable show me the bills that are not yet paid. I can import everything from the database to the jtable, but, what I need to do is import just the bills that are not paid?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous post some code and try to explain better

Comment: Write a query to select relevant data on basis of CancelColumn!='C' and get this data using JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using JDBC
you should write something like 
`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE BILL_PAYED <> 'C'`

Comment: Thanks dude! It works!!